# Tomcat 6 on Centos 5 - only RPMs

Tags: centos, tomcat, yum, rpm

I'm going through the exercise of setting up Tomcat 6 on CentOS 5 using RPM packages. Right now I'm stuck with old versions of tomcat5-jsp-2.0-api and tomcat5-servlet-2.4-api-5.5.27-7.jpp5, since they are required by jakarta-taglibs-standard:

```
$ rpm -q --requires jakarta-taglibs-standard
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
servletapi5 >= 0:5.0.16
tomcat5-jsp-2.0-api >= 0:5.0.16
xalan-j2 >= 2.6.0
```

How can I move to a complete RPM-based solution for Tomcat 6, without having the old Tomcat 5 RPMS installed?

---

Just to clarify, this is not out of pure curiosity, but because the old dependencies now break my update

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've done this, but in general, you should be able to remove all of the Java-related RPMs from CentOS / RHEL, set up [JPackage](http://www.jpackage.org/) as a repository, and install Tomcat 6 from there.  JPackage's RPMs are newer and more comprehensive than what CentOS / RHEL provide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. JPackage seems to include a taglib rpm depending on the old tomcat5 package : http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/jpackage/1.7/generic/free/repodata/repoview/jakarta-taglibs-standard-0-1.1.1-8jpp.html

Comment: Use JPackage 5.0. Although it's labeled "WIP," it's almost ready for release and should be plenty stable, and it contains tomcat6.

Comment: is the JPackage project dead? no updates for a year from looking at the site?

Comment: They don't have any major news to post on their site, but they're continuing to release packages.  (Scroll down to "Recent JPackage 6.0 RPMs" on their main site and you'll see a number of packages built within the last month.)