# Tomcat6 on RHEL 5.5

Tags: java, yum, rhel5, tomcat6

Based on the answer to a [similar question (CentOS)](https://serverfault.com/questions/54402/tomcat-6-on-centos-5-only-rpms) I have installed the jPackage .repo file and attempted `sudo yum install tomcat6`. I am met with the following error messages:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-1.4.2.0-40jpp.115.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-5 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: /usr/bin/rebuild-security-providers is needed by package java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-1.4.2.0-40jpp.115.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-5)
java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-1.4.2.0-40jpp.115.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-5 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: /usr/bin/rebuild-security-providers is needed by package java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-1.4.2.0-40jpp.115.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-5)
java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-1.4.2.0-40jpp.115.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-5 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: /usr/bin/rebuild-security-providers is needed by package java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-1.4.2.0-40jpp.115.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-5)
Error: Missing Dependency: /usr/bin/rebuild-security-providers is needed by package java-1.4.2-gcj-compat-1.4.2.0-40jpp.115.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-5)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I found a site stating that perhaps installing `rpm-build` was the solution to all my problems, but that was not the case – it's already installed.

I'd prefer to keep the package managed by a package manager (yum). Any experience with getting this to work?

The RHN packages only include Tomcat5. For reference this is RHEL 5.5 on Rackspace servers, to be used with Django/Solr/Haystack for site search. Moving from previous hosting on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS where the site was hosting/built with Tomcat6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem today. My solution was to just install the missing RPM by hand:

```
rpm -Uvh https://github.com/downloads/pallet/pallet/jpackage-utils-compat-el5-0.0.1-1.noarch.rpm
```

No more problems after that.

Comment: Link seems to be dead. Found a copy at https://github.com/downloads/pallet/pallet/jpackage-utils-compat-el5-0.0.1-1.noarch.rpm

Comment: Two years on, I just realized that this had a new answer. And it's better than my previous solution. Accepted answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Tomcat6 installed by first installing Tomcat5 from the RHN repository, which installed all dependencies successfully. After that, from the jPackage repo I installed the 1.6.0 version of the JDK, and then Tomcat6. I consider this to be an extremely dirty solution but since it works, I can't really argue with that.(Unless I find conflicts in the future.)